# Why load_dataset on Audiofolder with metadata is returning Filenotfound error?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, dataset, huggingface-transformers, kaggle

I am using Kaggle notebook kernels. I have a folder ‘traindata’ in my working directory that contains audio files and a metadata.csv file (you can see teh audio files, and the .csv file in the outputlist below). The .csv file contains a column ‘file_name’ containing the file names of all audiofiles. In my first notebook, when I try to load this data using load_dataset function (https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/audio_load#audiofolder-with-metadata), there is absolutely no problem. It loads perfectly as expected. However, when I run exactly the same code, in a 2nd Kaggle notebook, I get Filenotfound error. Full details are as follows. Can someone help me with this, as I intend to use the 2nd notebook for a different prediction models/ approach?

```
os.listdir("/kaggle/working/traindata")

['17d469e3c0f8.mp3',
 '7f64f5ad7c72.mp3',
 '792590a0c97b.mp3',
 '40a932482ffa.mp3',
 '20bff6808089.mp3',
 '072c952790a8.mp3',
 'b960faf6e6c9.mp3',
 '7144e5a3951c.mp3',
 'metadata.csv',
 'e101861d7fc6.mp3',
 'dec206df575b.mp3',
 'fd9da8a487a6.mp3',
 'd4bf563e8d74.mp3',
 'a1db8eecfa15.mp3',
 'c4de30d87c19.mp3',
 '35ab3905df36.mp3',
 'd0dcd7a9aa9d.mp3',
 'd510c4a0f4c3.mp3',
 '67a9e9be989d.mp3',
 '665f9d30c16c.mp3',
 '6cc0c4fcd376.mp3',
 'bc11e6300bab.mp3',
 'f4f100cc5126.mp3',
 '82b81f884c22.mp3',
 'e3e147532ab4.mp3',
 'c4eb00849950.mp3',
 '86c743dbdffc.mp3',
 '1dc891cad82d.mp3',
 '05bb928d483e.mp3',
 'dcca4da43c55.mp3',
 '2ff894872320.mp3',
 '3df8624d57a5.mp3',
 'bdce6383b6a3.mp3',
 '9e156c339843.mp3',
 '45c2362f6c24.mp3',
 '802b1445767e.mp3',
 'c6d7f0e0d016.mp3',
 '151abc026c93.mp3',
 'a1317f179adb.mp3',
 '83e1b5ce808a.mp3',
 '278ed2187132.mp3',
 '90b8207f80a3.mp3',
 '7989b39c6806.mp3',
 '77738ec9edbc.mp3',
 '3ea951d7af47.mp3',
 'e3665ff03a0c.mp3',
 '6c4e4d9823ac.mp3',
 '27846b8f8edd.mp3',
 '8df70760f935.mp3',
 'd6f06a5c0e02.mp3',
 'e2ab17915a45.mp3',
 '16841afc8002.mp3',
 '284eeb420025.mp3',
 '99e567500082.mp3',
 'aa101d9351a2.mp3',
 '2d97709e1321.mp3',
 '1bcdd2ab7204.mp3',
 'f01dd698a636.mp3',
 '52cb9dc45a60.mp3',
 '56497258f4d4.mp3',
 'b81628311b82.mp3',
 'af9cfe48184c.mp3',
 '87961540a611.mp3',
 'aad63a719baf.mp3',
 '67ff0d4f0abe.mp3',
 'ba00881866dd.mp3',
 'b3793565c709.mp3',
 '7ceca0306fa1.mp3',
 '9db958779825.mp3',
 '24bc00853dfd.mp3',
 '82facfcaf4af.mp3',
 '9e849a13f4d2.mp3',
 '5b7577a65f36.mp3',
 '0e0cd7ae0a4b.mp3',
 '948012d60dbc.mp3',
 'dce2b585586b.mp3',
 'cc29d450c5fc.mp3',
 '178c4fbf1765.mp3',
 'ab2905e4bc54.mp3',
 'ef8953b95e6a.mp3',
 'c6eda3ea8c01.mp3',
 '244d9567f4ba.mp3',
 '078b6f9629b2.mp3',
 '75fb7aa16b1c.mp3',
 'c7d2473e379f.mp3',
 'd29197658275.mp3',
 '9680b1e57366.mp3',
 '403f13f1b957.mp3',
 '85391aa9a25f.mp3',
 '36229829da97.mp3',
 'ec9c15cb1e78.mp3',
 '84eb69de8f29.mp3',
 '973f2efec47a.mp3',
 'd4541f36bb70.mp3',
 '15b565b3a352.mp3',
 '9574a61cc33c.mp3',
 'a8d6bf1285d5.mp3',
 '62e2a304f67d.mp3',
 'e7b575cc3a88.mp3',
 '69a85e880d81.mp3',
 '3beed37e15c5.mp3']

train_dataset = load_dataset("audiofolder", data_dir="/kaggle/working/traindata")
train_dataset

╭─────────────────────────────── Traceback (most recent call last) ────────────────────────────────╮
│ in <module>:1                                                                                    │
│                                                                                                  │
│ ❱ 1 train_dataset = load_dataset("audiofolder", data_dir="/kaggle/working/traindata", drop_l     │
│   2                                                                                              │
│   3 train_dataset                                                                                │
│   4                                                                                              │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/load.py:1664 in load_dataset                    │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1661 │   ignore_verifications = ignore_verifications or save_infos                             │
│   1662 │                                                                                         │
│   1663 │   # Create a dataset builder                                                            │
│ ❱ 1664 │   builder_instance = load_dataset_builder(                                              │
│   1665 │   │   path=path,                                                                        │
│   1666 │   │   name=name,                                                                        │
│   1667 │   │   data_dir=data_dir,                                                                │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/load.py:1490 in load_dataset_builder            │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1487 │   if use_auth_token is not None:                                                        │
│   1488 │   │   download_config = download_config.copy() if download_config else DownloadConfig(  │
│   1489 │   │   download_config.use_auth_token = use_auth_token                                   │
│ ❱ 1490 │   dataset_module = dataset_module_factory(                                              │
│   1491 │   │   path,                                                                             │
│   1492 │   │   revision=revision,                                                                │
│   1493 │   │   download_config=download_config,                                                  │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/load.py:1238 in dataset_module_factory          │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1235 │   │   │   │   if isinstance(e1, OfflineModeIsEnabled):                                  │
│   1236 │   │   │   │   │   raise ConnectionError(f"Couln't reach the Hugging Face Hub for datas  │
│   1237 │   │   │   │   if isinstance(e1, FileNotFoundError):                                     │
│ ❱ 1238 │   │   │   │   │   raise FileNotFoundError(                                              │
│   1239 │   │   │   │   │   │   f"Couldn't find a dataset script at {relative_to_absolute_path(c  │
│   1240 │   │   │   │   │   │   f"Couldn't find '{path}' on the Hugging Face Hub either: {type(e  │
│   1241 │   │   │   │   │   ) from None                                                           │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
FileNotFoundError: Couldn't find a dataset script at /kaggle/working/audiofolder/audiofolder.py or any data file in
the same directory. Couldn't find 'audiofolder' on the Hugging Face Hub either: FileNotFoundError: Couldn't find 
file at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/huggingface/datasets/master/datasets/audiofolder/audiofolder.py
```